# How do I disable JavaDoc code inspection for getters/setters in IntelliJ IDEA 11?

Tags: coding-style, ide, intellij-idea, javadoc, code-inspection

In our project properties (getters/setters) are already quite self-descriptive so we don't see the reason to add JavaDoc for those.

So I was wondering: Is it possible to disable JavaDoc check (code inspection "Declaration has JavaDoc problems") only for getters/setters and leave it for the other methods in IntelliJ IDEA?
I was trying to find the solution but so far - no luck.

Thanks in advance

Update: found this [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-43830#tab=History) as feature suggestion for IDEA. It seems it is still not resolved. 
I wonder if there is some custom code inspection implementation to deal with it somehow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604387/why-idea-shows-javadoc-as-error

Answer (score 0):

I'm using IntelliJ 2018.1

Under the options in the *Declaration has Javadoc problems* inspection you can mark the checkbox that says *Ignore simple property accessors*

Step by Step guide:

1. Press CTRL + ALT + S to open Settings
2. Navigate to Editor > Inspections
3. Open the Javadoc option
4. Choose Declaration has Javadoc problems, which opens the side menu
5. In bottom of this menu that's a checkbox *Ignore simple Property Accessors*