# Why IDEA shows JavaDoc as error?

Tags: intellij-idea

```
/**
     * @param string
     * @throws ApplicationException
     */
```

IDEA highlight the 'string' and tells "No documentation found". Why is that so?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Write some documentation for the `string` param or adjust the **Declaration has Javadoc problems** inspection settings so that such problems are not reported:

[image: Declaration has Javadoc problems]

Comment: A faster way to do it is via the Alt+Return shortcut, there you can disable the inspection globally or for this class/method.

Answer (score 3):

My development tools is `Android Studio`, I meet the problem like you.
You just do it like so.

From `File` => `Settings`

[image]